# Question about the search page/bar

Tags: discussion

This question may be too broad to be relevant, and it is maybe (probably ?) a duplicate.

Even though I am almost all day long on TeX.SE, I always go through google to fallback here to find relevant answers to my questions (yes, it's a very clever workflow).

While writing this post I just figured there was a dedicated [search page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search) on this site (which I had no idea about up to know) ! This page (I guess) works the same way than the search bar that is always visible.

However, when writing a question, in particular the title, the page proposes former questions to ease the research for duplicates.

**Here comes my question**

Why don't the main search bar or the search page propose such dynamic information ?

A subsidiary question that I just found: why is there no "search" button near "questions" ... if there is a separate search page ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: We had this question a couple of times, unfortunately I cannot find because the search bar is so bad at finding things .... My impression is that the search bar is bad by design because the dynamic search which one gets when asking a questions is much more resource intensive. If you want to make your life easier, there are users scripts/addons which automatically use a google search in the search bar.

Comment: @samcarter, this is both funny and a shame, not being able to find a question about a search tool. I guess this is the reason I did not find this either. Do you know is the main search bar and the search bar on the dedicated page give the same results ?

Comment: I have no idea! If I follow the link to the search page, it looks like this for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtuJJ.png

Comment: I generally search by starting to ask a question unless I've memorised a key phrase and sort order. (E.g. 'vanilla' - by vote - the q&a about installing from upstream on linux (with debian bias.) With answers, I'm more inclined to answer if I can't find it easilish. I figure SE must like duplicate qnswers, but not questions, a lot.

Comment: For Ti*k*Z and pgfplots questions it really helps to start a google picture search with `site:tex.stackexchange.com` in it. For forest questions, it helps to go through cfr's answers, and for beamer to go through @samcarter's answers. ;-)

Comment: related question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187773/link-up-the-excellent-search-engine-that-gives-questions-that-may-already-have?noredirect=1 , https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5167/search-box-vs-question-title

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268318/why-is-the-this-question-might-exist-search-better-than-the-normal-search